# Data extraction from NVD website

Tags: security, data-analysis, data-extraction, data-science, reliability

I am trying to obtain vulnerability related data from National vulnerability database (NVD). However, the data is not organized properly and as I am a electrical engineer, I have a hard time extracting this data to a csv or excel file. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi Could you give us a link to the data you want to extract? Also want are you using for your analysis ? R ?

Comment: https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/search-results?search_type=last3months&cves=on&uscert_vn=on&startIndex=40. R or Mathematica is what I am planning to use for analysis

Comment: Hi VIDHYA Thank you for the link. What data do you want from the page? Eg CVE-2016-5388 and the summary Etc? Also what problem did you have?

Comment: I need to extract the data to a csv file and I need CVE number, published date, disclosed date, severrity, affected software, etc. I am a mathematician and not very good at programming. I know I will have to write a script to extract these information. So may be I am looking for a starting point!